# Temporarily disable all addons

Tags: scripting, interface, add-on

For troubleshooting purposes, I want to temporarily disable all addons, and then re-enable them after running some tests. Any easy way to do this other than manually?

Answer (score 6):

**[addon_utils](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2800/15543)**

> Blender has a module it uses for addon management called addon_utils,
>   this isn't in the API docs and is only for internal usage. But its a
>   fairly straightforward
>   module.

**Disable all addons**

Will call unregister on all registered addons.

```
from addon_utils import disable_all
disable_all()
```

**Reset all addons**

```
from addon_utils import reset_all
reset_all()
```

both two liners can be run from text editor, or python console.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
blender --factory-startup
```