# How to disable all addons while using blender with --background command line option?

Tags: command-line

I found the commandline parameter `--addons`. But when I leave the parameter value empty it does not have any effect. Blender still loads all addons. Is it possible to disable addons when using `--background`?

Comment: My reading of the --addons parameter is that it is to **enable** extra addons, not to disable the ones that are already enabled so if you leave the parameter value empty it will have no effect. I don't know whether [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89692/temporarily-disable-all-addons) answer still applies to the current Blender version or whether you can activate it for your use?

Comment: A much better aproach than my research but i try to achive to boot blender with loading addons.